# Visual studio don't have parameter detectMultiScale

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm newbie at here. I don't know why my visual studio code doesn't show parameter detectMultiScale.
What should I fix it? I attach image here for detail. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD9A8.png)

I try to reinstall for several times but it still not show parameter.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in the *settings.json* to enable type hints

```json
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
```

[image]